# Why are my forms authentication tickets expiring so fast?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

I'm using forms authentication in an ASP.NET application. I configure the `FormsAuthenticationTicket` to expire in 1 year but it actually expires after 1 hour or so. I can't figure out why.

Here is all the code involved in the login process:

```
public static bool Login(int id)
{
    try
    {
        string securityToken = UserHelper.AuthenticateUser(id);

        DateTime expiryDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
             1, id.ToString(), DateTime.Now, expiryDate, true,
             securityToken, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

        string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
        cookie.Expires = expiryDate;

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate"
    decryptionKey="AutoGenerate" validation="SHA1" />
    <compilation debug="true">
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
...
```

Is something wrong with my approach? Why is it expiring so fast?

**EDIT**

Global.asax code:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.PhysicalPath.EndsWith(".aspx") || Request.PhysicalPath.EndsWith(".axd") || Request.PhysicalPath.EndsWith(".ashx"))
        SecurityManager.SetPrincipal();
}
```

SetPrincipal Code:

```
public static void SetPrincipal()
{
    ILivrePrincipal principal = null;
    FormsIdentity identity;
    UrlParameters urlParameters = UrlParametersHelper.GetUrlParameters(HttpContext.Current.Request);

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        identity = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;

        User userProfile;
        urlParameters.SecurityToken = (((FormsIdentity)identity).Ticket).UserData;
        try
        {
            userProfile = UserHelper.GetUser(urlParameters.SecurityToken);
            UserHelper.UpdateLastActiveOn(userProfile);
            principal = new AuthenticatedPrincipal(identity, userProfile);
        }
        catch
        {
            //TODO: Log an exception
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            principal = new AnonymousPrincipal(new GuestIdentity(), UserHelper.GetUser(null));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        principal = new AnonymousPrincipal(new GuestIdentity(), UserHelper.GetUser(null));
    }

    HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `timeout="2880"` (which specifies 2 days)?

Comment: @Gabe Thank you. I agree to you. It's an error, but still does not explain why are my login session expiring in about an hour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is your problem.

```
<machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate" 
            decryptionKey="AutoGenerate" 
            validation="SHA1"/>
```

ASP will generate a new machine key every time the app pool recycles.  Which could reasonably happen every hour.

The machine key is used to encrypt and decrypt your FormsAuthentication cookie.  If it changes, the cookie on your browser is no longer any good.  So the system will treat you as if you have never logged on.

Try generating a static key and adding it to the configuration file.  Should look something like this:

```
<machineKey  
    validationKey="21F090935F6E49C2C797F69(snip)F1B72A7F0A281B"          
    decryptionKey="ABAA84D7EC4BB56D75D(snip)B8BF91CFCD64568A145BE59719F"
    validation="SHA1"
    decryption="AES"
/>
```

Generate yourself a key [here](http://www.a2zmenu.com/utility/machine-key-generator.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with the code.  What browser are you using, perhaps it doesn't recognize the expiration date of 1 year?  I would look at the response headers with fiddler or some such tool and see what's actually being sent.

Comment: I get the problem with any browser

Comment: and what does the response header look like?

Comment: I agree that the first place to look is at the raw cookies / traffic.  Firefox  with the Firebug and Firecookie plugins is one excellent way to scope out the situation (that's how I debugged my issues with forms authentication).

Answer (score 1):

This might help http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910439/

My guess is that the cookie is expiring before the ticket.  The above article shows you ways to debug to see if that is indeed the case.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can see that is non-standard is that you are passing id.ToString() to the FormsAuthenticationTicket constructor. I usually pass the username in this parameter. Not sure whether this will make a difference, but worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using anything else in your application that might cause a timeout? 
Automatically logging you out if in-proc session states expire for example.

I assume you've got some code in your Global.asax to process the authenticated request too?

Comment: I don't think I'm using anything that would cause a timeout. I added more information about the authentication code.