# .Net Web Application - Don't precompile

Tags: asp.net, webforms

We recently converted a website made with .Net WebForms from a Web Site project, to a Web Application Project.

This is all well and good, except it's now a pain because to change any of our code-behind files we have to rebuild the whole site, whereas before all we had to do was save the code-behind file.
This means changing pages in logged in areas requires not only rebuilding the whole Web Application, but then logging in again for a user.
Is there a way to remove the precompile option while running locally so we can debug as we used to with a Web Site project?

I have tried removing the `<compilers>` section from the web.config, and also removed the `<compilation>` too, but neither seem to have made a difference.

EDIT:
I realise now I wasn't very clear. I'm talking about debugging the site locally, not when publishing.

Comment: When publishing the site - you should have an option to untick the precompile checkbox? It should be under settings -> File publish options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Web Application projects load from a DLL; they have no option to compile source at runtime.

You should specify a fixed validation & decryption keys in Web.config so that users don't need to log in again after deploying ([more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19329485/34397)).

Comment: That is exactly what I didn't want to hear.. Thanks though!

Comment: Why? You should have an automated deployment process that makes this easy.

Comment: Deploying is fine, it's just debugging locally where the issue is. To make a small change to a codebehind file I have to rebuild my whole web application which takes about 30 seconds, whereas before when the project was a Website project, I just had to refresh the page I was editting.